# Epic not returning stream in Redux-Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm testing out using `redux-observable` with a side-project and I'm running into this problem repeatedly: `Uncaught TypeError: combineEpics: one of the provided Epics "handleSearchEpic" does not return a stream. Double check you're not missing a return statement!`

I've referenced the redux observable docs and several other examples online but I can't identify what I might be missing. Below are my actions and the epic in question.

```
export const searchContent = query => {
  return {
    type: SEARCH_CONTENT,
    query
  }
}

const returnSearchContent = searchResults => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: RETURN_SEARCH_CONTENT,
      searchResults
    });
  }
}

// Epics
export const handleSearchEpic = action$ => {
  action$.ofType(SEARCH_CONTENT)
    .mergeMap(action => axios.get(`...SOME_API_ENDPOINT`))
    .map(res => returnSearchContent(res))
}

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  handleSearchEpic
);
```

Here is the root of the application and the store config:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);
const store = createStore(Reducer, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `handleSearchEpic` epic is an arrow function **with a block** but does not actually return the stream.

#### Bad

```
export const handleSearchEpic = action$ => { // <-- start of block
  // vvvvvvv missing return
  action$.ofType(SEARCH_CONTENT)
    .mergeMap(action => axios.get(`...SOME_API_ENDPOINT`))
    .map(res => returnSearchContent(res))
} // <-- end of block
```

#### Good

```
export const handleSearchEpic = action$ => {
  return action$.ofType(SEARCH_CONTENT)
    .mergeMap(action => axios.get(`...SOME_API_ENDPOINT`))
    .map(res => returnSearchContent(res))
}
```

#### Implicit return?

Alternatively, you can remove the block and use an implicit return, which may be what you meant to do?

```
export const handleSearchEpic = action$ => // <--- no block
  action$.ofType(SEARCH_CONTENT)
    .mergeMap(action => axios.get(`...SOME_API_ENDPOINT`))
    .map(res => returnSearchContent(res));
```

---

A very common mistake, which is why I added the error message you provided, but it didn't seem to make the solution understandable. Any suggestions how I can improve the error message?

> combineEpics: one of the provided Epics "handleSearchEpic" does not return a stream. Double check you're not missing a return statement!

Comment: Oh hey, thanks! I really enjoyed your talk about the library. Top notch.

Comment: I think my mistake might've just been a rookie mistake here. I was definitely trying to emulate an implicit return, but forgot about the braces. I think improving the error message might just be as simple as adding on `Double check you're either using a return statement or an es6 implicit return`. Maybe some other folks might have some better input, though?

Comment: Why does an error message have to be just one line and, usually as a result, extremely unclear?  Why can't it be about 15 lines long like your answer and showing what the most common mistake is that causes the error and very helpfully show your two different approaches to getting it to work? Error messages are still in medieval times